# Can I use loops to minimize ES6 import statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I checked the doc for "import" and feel it's impossible to treat the imported names like array elements. Any suggestion to deal with such a situation is welcome.

```js
import C1 from '../samples/sample1'
import C3 from '../samples/sample3'
import C4 from '../samples/sample4'
import C5 from '../samples/sample5'
import C6 from '../samples/sample6'
import C7 from '../samples/sample7'
import C8 from '../samples/sample8'
import C9 from '../samples/sample9'
......
......
<Route path='/sample1' component={C1} />
<Route path='/sample3' component={C3} />
<Route path='/sample4' component={C4} />
<Route path='/sample5' component={C5} />
<Route path='/sample6' component={C6} />
<Route path='/sample7' component={C7} />
<Route path='/sample8' component={C8} />
<Route path='/sample9' component={C9} />
```

Comment: I guess you can programmatically create that file during your build process from the directory structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this using ES6 imports because they are [static](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#static-module-structure).

This means that you must specify what you import and export at compile time and can’t react to changes at runtime.

Using something like an array would mean that the code must run before the system can confidently know what's getting imported.

The only way currently* (see bellow) to get around this is to use the [`require` CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules) approach.

```
const routes = Array
  .from({ length: 10 }) // create array of 10 elements
  .map((_, i) => require(`../samples/sample${i + 1}`)) // map each element to an imported file using the index
  .map((c, i) => ( // map each component to a route
    <Route
      path={`/sample${i + 1}`}
      component={c}
    />
  ))
```

You can also combine the two `map` loops into one:

```
const routes = Array
  .from({ length: 10 })
  .map((c, i) => (
    <Route
      path={`/sample${i + 1}`}
      component={require(`../samples/sample${i + 1}`)}
    />
  ))
```

That being said, more likely that not, you probably don't need 10 different sample components. Instead of creating individual components for minor differences, why not use a single component and pass it a type that determines it's behavior?

```
import Sample from './sample'

const routes = Array
  .from({ length: 10 }) // create array of 10 elements
  .map((c, i) => 
     <Route // map each component to a route 
       path={`/sample${i + 1}`}
       component={props => <Sample type={i + 1} {...props} />}
       {/*                         ^ now every sample knows which one it is */}
     />
   )
```

In fact, you might not need multiple routes as well and could use a single-route with a dynamic segment representing the sample type and passes that along to the component.

```
import Sample from './sample'

<Route path="/sample/:type" component={({ params }) => <Sample type={params.type} />} />
```

---

There is currently a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) to add dynamic importing to ES6 modules:

```
Promise.all(
  Array
    .from({ length: 10 }) // create array of 10 elements
    .map((_, i) => import(`../samples/sample${i + 1}`)) // map each element to a promise resolving to the imported file
).then(components => {  // map each component to a route
  const routes = components
    .map((c, i) => (
      <Route
        path={`/sample${i + 1}`}
        component={c}
      />
    ))
})
```

Comment: I followed your "require"-based solution and it works! And that's what I wanted!

Comment: Glad to help mate.

Comment: All samples are test codes I use to prove a specific solution so I don't want to merge them into one component.An interesting finding is that I didn't intend to export the existing sample2.js  but webpack forces me to. I guess webpack knows(by analyzing the code) that I want to export samples but not smart enough to know which files I really intend to export. A big THANKS to you

Answer (score 1):

create index.js for exporting all files form one folder

if your component default exported then first import in your index file and then export

import c1 from '../samples/sample1';
export c1 from '../samples/sample1';

if your component not exported as default you can direct export

export * from '../samples/sample1';

and import where you want to use

import { c1, c2 } from '../samples';

It will shorten the import statements