# Dynamically load versioned API routes into express.Router

Tags: node.js, express

My routes live in `./src/routes/api/v0/`, here's an example route:

```
//src/routes/api/v0/dogs.js
import { Router } from 'express'

const router = Router()

router.get('/dogs', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'List of all dogs' })
})

router.post('/dogs', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: `Created a dog: ${req.body}` })
})

router.put('/dogs/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  res.json({ message: `Dog ${id} mutated into ${req.body}` })
})

router.delete('/dogs/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  res.json({ message: `Dog ${id} is gone` })
})

export { router as dogs }
```

Assume that there is a another similar file with routes, `cats.js`, omitted here for brevity. I'm exporting both modules from `index.js`:

```
//src/routes/api/v0/index.js
export * from './cats'
export * from './dogs'
```

Then, I'm loading them via intermediary, like this:

```
//src/routes/api/index.js
import { Router } from 'express'
import { cats, dogs } from './v0'
const v0 = Router()

v0.use('/v0', cats)
v0.use('/v0', dogs)

export { v0 }
```

And finally loading them in `server.js`:

```
//src/server.js
import v0 from './routes/api'
...
app.use('/api', v0)
...
```

Is there a way to load individual route modules into `express.Router` (the `v0` in my `src/routes/api/index.js`) without passing every single module my hand? Something like:

```
//src/routes/api/index.js
import { Router } from 'express'
import * as apiV0 from './v0'

const v0 = Router()

v0.use('/v0', magically feed it apiV0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to export an array of routers, rather than naming each one.  Then, you can just iterate through that array to add them all in a generic way.  So, instead of importing each by name like you do here:

```
//src/routes/api/index.js
import { Router } from 'express'
import { cats, dogs } from './v0'
const v0 = Router()

v0.use('/v0', cats)
v0.use('/v0', dogs)

export { v0 }
```

You could export and then import an array of routers and then iterate the array:

```
//src/routes/api/index.js
import { Router } from 'express'
import { allRouters } from './v0'
const v0 = Router()

for (const router of allRouters) {
    v0.use('/v0', router)
}

export { v0 }
```

In fact, you could export both the individual named routers like you have now and the array of routers if you wanted and then the importing code would be free to use either individual named routers or the whole array.

---

**Addition to this answer after OP edited the question**

Your edit to the question that shows this:

```
//src/routes/api/v0/index.js
export * from './cats'
export * from './dogs'
```

creates some complications for any sort of automatic collection of all these routes.  ES6 `import` and `export` can not be dynamically determined.  On purpose, ES6 requires static analysis of imports and exports to be possible.  So, you can't import or export in a loop of code.  Here's a discussion of that topic:

[Can I use loops to minimize ES6 import statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117756/can-i-use-loops-to-minimize-es6-import-statements)

If you were using `require()`, then you could build a single module that could just either read a config file and load all your route files by looking in the file system or by reading a config file that specifies them all.  But, you can do that with ES6 `import` and `export`.  So, as best I know, if you're going to use `import` and `export`, you will have to specify the imports manually.  By putting them in an array before exporting the collection of routes, you will at least only have to do the manual declaration once instead of twice (which is an improvement over your current code).

Here's importing them manually, but then exporting them in the array which can more easily be processed:

```
//src/routes/api/v0/index.js
import {dogs} from './dogs'
import {cats} from './cats'

export const allRouters = [dogs, cats];
```

Then, you could install them:

```
//src/routes/api/index.js
import { Router } from 'express'
import { allRouters } from './v0'
const v0 = Router()

for (const router of allRouters) {
    v0.use('/v0', router)
}

export { v0 }
```

Comment: I like this! Care to elaborate how would you export those routes as an array? Say that I've dogs.js and cats.js, both with their respective routes defined. How do I get them into api/index.js as an combined array of routes?

Comment: @boojum - Well, you showed `import { cats, dogs } from './v0'` so it seems like you already had the `cats` and `dogs` routers in the same file and being exported separately.  You would just change that to export them in an array named `allRouters`.   If that's not what you had, then I'm confused about what you have right now and how you're currently doing it that you want to improve on.

Comment: Heh, sorry for the confusion! I updated my question, hopeful its clearer now.

Comment: @boojum - See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain the case import / export, it explains why I got `undefined` with my various attempts. As I do want to stick to ES6 syntax, I would be happy to accept your answer. But the example you provided is not working for me: https://paste.pics/8AEEV

Comment: @boojum - What exactly does not work?  Do you get an error?  I've modified the `export` syntax in my answer to `export const allRouters = [dogs, cats];`.

Comment: See the screenshot from you previous comment. Adding `const` complains about `Identifier 'dogs' has already been declared`, see here: https://paste.pics/8AELI

Comment: Hey, its fine - I took a different approach and decided to go with `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fs` module to read a file and export its functions. You can look at my code [here](https://github.com/mandaputtra/express-mongo-starter/blob/fb712e58890c0348f5f6dd5d1121b3be427fd3bb/models/index.js#L18).

the `__dirname` I use was the models dirname. then you can use this magic one line require on start of your app.

```
import initFunction from 'src/routes'
import { Router } from 'express'

initFunction(Router()) // dont forget your express instance

initFunction
```

Comment: Your solution, using `require()` and `readdir()`, will work and is the first thing coming up on SO and elsewhere. Although - due to the personal preferences - I'm interested in ES6 `import`/`export`. For that reason, it would be unfair of me to accept your - working - solution. Regardless, thanks for your time!